# How to do a vertical scale in android textview

Tags: android, textview, scaling

I am looking for scaling the textview in vertical, I found that there is ScaleX but not ScaleY.

There is any solution to do the scaling?

Comment: Can you please paste your solution as answer. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size :) Another solution is to create a custom view that applies a scale factor on the Y axis before calling super.draw().

Comment: Yes I found the solution to create an extended textview and put that:
canvas.scale(1f, .8f);